# Upgrade to 2.4.3 p2 Are Opensearch and Elasticsearch both needed or can I use just one?

Tags: elasticsearch, magento2.4.3, opensearch

I am upgrading from 2.4.3 to 2.4.3 p2 and just want to know, do I need both OpenSearch and Elasticsearch, or is just 1 sufficient.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not 100% sure but I believe you still need both. I think opensearch is on the frontend and elasticsearch handles the backend.

Answer (score 1):

You only need one. Who you can use will be dependant on your hosting provider.

OpenSearch is a fork of ElasticSearch by AWS. As I understand it, OpenSearch was essentially created because ElasticSearch updated it's license to prevent others from operating a managed ElasticSearch service.

Answer (score 0):

Magento 2.4.3-p2 supports both **ElasticSearch 7.16** & **OpenSearch 1.2**
Both are search engines, so you can pick either of these.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use elasticsearch, as opensearch is only supported for M2.4.5 for now. Please review the below image for the system requirements.

[image]

For more details on system requirements check [this](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/install-gde/system-requirements.html).

For more details on elasticsearch check [this](https://orba.co/how-does-elasticsearch-work-with-magento/).

Thanks!